# Pass Variable Between classes in python, (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write')

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Below is a fragment of my code, i tried passing an instance variable from the class DiscussPage to anothe class quesAnsweredPage

```
class DiscussPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def post(self):
                self.Ques_tit = "Content"
                classname = questAnsweredPage()
                classname.setValue(self.Ques_tit,self.Ques_tit)

class questAnsweredPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    Can_I = "yes"
    def setValue(self,que,title):
        self.response.write(que)
```

The Code above returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "B:\Eclipse World\Google App Engine\App Engine Dev\Jambite_Extended\JambitesCurrent\Jambitesupdated by bel\main.py", line 2686, in post
    classname.setValue(self.Ques_tit,self.Ques_tit)
  File "B:\Eclipse World\Google App Engine\App Engine Dev\Jambite_Extended\JambitesCurrent\Jambitesupdated by bel\main.py", line 2774, in setValue
    self.response.write(que)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How do i resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the signature of classes based on webapp2.RequestHandler ( specifically the init method)

From the docs http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler we get

```
 class webapp2.RequestHandler(request=None, response=None)[source]
```

So when you instantiate an instance of a class inheriting from RequestHandler you need to initialise it correctly.

You code should read

```
 classname = questAnsweredPage(self.request,self.response)
```

Now why you would use a variable name `classname` to hold an instance of a class is a whole separate style issue ;-)

Comment: Except that there doesn't seem to be any reason why (a) he would make questAnsweredPage a subclass of RequestHandler and (b) he would use a separate class at all, instead of just adding a method to DiscussPage.

Comment: Agreed I wasn't even going to go into that.  Sometimes people do have a valid reason to call another handler, but couldn;t really be bothered going down that rat hole ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The error is probably because `self.response` can only be called inside a `get()` or `post()` method.